# How to complete remove software?

Tags: software-uninstall, purge

How could we uninstall completely a software? Knowing that the command `sudo apt remove (or purge) software` doesn't allow us to remove a software, because of the following comment on `man apt` :

> Removing a package removes all packaged data, but leaves usually small
>   (modified) user configuration files behind, in case the remove was an
>   accident. Just issuing an installation request for the accidentally
>   removed package will restore its function as before in that case.

Comment: `apt remove` removes the package, `apt purge` removes the package plus system-wide configuration. I think there's usually no general command to remove the user configuration as well other than manually removing related files in the home directory and maybe keys in dconf.

Comment: I would just run a `locate` on the name of the software and you should find all files relating to it on the system. Also checking the `.config`, `.cache`, etc, directories in `~`. That's the kind of local configuration it likely means.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there's a way to automatically remove user config files using `apt`.

But I think `apt` keeps them after removal of the package only if they were modified by the user. So after using `apt purge`, you would have to remove any files in your home folder which have been modified post-install. You could use the `find` or `locate` command-line utilities from your home folder for this.